# how to display the output in oracle with the select query

Tags: mysql, oracle, select, replace, linefeed

Below is my `EMP` table with some sample data

```
EMPNAME | WORK_DATA | WORK_HOURS
---------------------------------
abc     | 01-SEP-13 |     9
xyz     | 01-SEP-13 |     8
abc     | 02-SEP-13 |     8
xyz     | 02-SEP-13 |     7
abc     | 01-OCT-13 |     5
xyz     | 01-OCT-13 |     7
abc     | 02-OCT-13 |     8
xyz     | 02-OCT-13 |     7
```

And now I want this to be displayed as in oracle using select statement

```
EMPNAME | SEP_MONTH_WORKING_HOURS | OCT_MONTH_WORKING_HOURS 
-----------------------------------------------------------
abc     | 17                      | 13
xyz     | 15                      | 14
```

Seond doubt is:

```
EMPNAME | SEP_MONTH_WORKING_HOURS | RANK 
-----------------------------------------------------------
xyz     | 15                      | 1
abc     | 17                      | 2
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Shoudnt SEP_MONTH_WORKING be 17 for abc ?

Comment: Second question answer is :

select 
empid,work_date OCT_MONTH_WORK_HOURS,rownum rank
from 
(select empid,sum(case when extract (month from work_date) = 10 then work_hours end) work_date from temp group by empid order by work_date)

Answer (score 2):

This should work using `extract`:

```
select empname, 
  sum(case when  extract(month from work_data) = 9 then work_hours end) sept_work_hours,
  sum(case when  extract(month from work_data) = 10 then work_hours end) oct_work_hours
from emp
group by empname
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ad88/6)

*Please note, abcs employee for september should be 17 instead of 19.*

Comment: Man your too good... this worked for me...  thanks alot :)

Comment: @user2870912 please accept the answer if it worked for you.